# First-order linear mu-calculus?

Tags: reference-request, mu-calculus

There is linear $\mu$-calculus (see *e.g.* [1]) and first-order $\mu$-calculus (see *e.g.* [here](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1708-01.pdf)).

Has anybody studied *first-order linear $\mu$-calculus*?

[1]: Christian Dax, Martin Hofmann, Martin Lange:
*A Proof System for the Linear Time µ-Calculus*. FSTTCS 2006: 273-284